# Maven New project archetype list different

Tags: java, maven

If i go
File -> New -> Project when a project is already opened, I have a complete lists of archetypes :
[image]

But if i go File -> New -> Project after opening an empty project, I don't have a coplete lists of archetypes :
[image]

Isn't this weird ? If i make a new project, why does the current opened project have an influence ?

I'm a beginner, any details is appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: The checkbox "create from archetype" is uncheked. Also maybbe if opening from a already maven project the archetypes are preloaded, amd not with any other kind of project.

Comment: It doesn't work either: https://i.imgur.com/SFzeufs.png

Comment: I guess "if opening from a already maven project the archetypes are preloaded, amd not with any other kind of project" is the answer

Comment: To test that you cam add a minimal pom.xml to the non-maven prpject, right click on it, "Add as maven project", and when it finishes loading try again if the archetypes are now there.

Comment: what would a minimal pom.xml look like? Sorry i'm a total beginner with maven (and Java)

Comment: I think this would do
`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

</project>`

Answer (score 0):

Click the Create from archetype checkbox, then it will show a list of all the archetypes

Comment: This does not work either:
https://i.imgur.com/SFzeufs.png